# How to use order by for particular statement while using UNION ALL in android

Tags: android, sql-order-by, union-all

I just wanted to order only 2nd `SELECT` statement while using `UNION ALL` Condition. I wrote the Query as:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, product_code, product_name, product_category,discount, in_stock, price, brand 
    FROM ProductDetails 
    WHERE _id || ' ' || product_name || product_code 
    LIKE ? 
    UNION ALL SELECT _id, product_code, product_name, product_category,discount, in_stock, price, brand 
    FROM ProductDetails WHERE _id || ' ' || product_name || product_code 
    NOT LIKE ? ORDER BY brand ", new String[] { "%" +searchValue+ "%","%" +searchValue+"});
```

The above query is sorting total Union statement.

Can any one tell me how to Sort only 2nd `SELECT` statement ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that works in SQLite but it's worth a shot:

```
SELECT _id, product_code, product_name, product_category,discount, in_stock, price, brand 
FROM ProductDetails 
WHERE _id || ' ' || product_name || product_code 
LIKE ? 
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM (SELECT _id, product_code, product_name, product_category,discount, in_stock, price, brand 
FROM ProductDetails WHERE _id || ' ' || product_name || product_code 
NOT LIKE ? ORDER BY brand)
```

If that doesn't work you could make two seperate SQL queries and union them in java.

Answer (score 0):

Try isolating the 2nd SELECT with parentheses:

```
UNION ALL (SELECT _id, product_code, product_name, product_category,discount, in_stock, price, brand 
    FROM ProductDetails WHERE _id || ' ' || product_name || product_code 
    NOT LIKE ? ORDER BY brand)
```